# How to access dynamic route parameters as strings?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I have in my project a route set up as

```
  {
    path: '/change/:who',
    component: () => import('layouts/ChangeValue.vue'),
  },
```

When in the `ChangeValue` component, with the route `http://localhost:8080/#/change/michael`, I tried to access the `:who` parameter (which should be `michael`):

```
  setup() {
    let user = ref<string>('');
    let route = useRoute();
    user.value = route.params.who;
(...)
```

This raises an error at compilation time:

```
index.js?a29e:529 [webpack-dev-server] TS2322: Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    19 |     let user = ref<string>('');
    20 |     let route = useRoute();
  > 21 |     user.value = route.params.who;
       |     ^^^^^^^^^^
    22 |
    23 |
    24 |     interface CorveesDescI {
```

**My main problem is that I do not understand why the type of `route.params.who` is expected to be `string[]` and not simply `string`.**

Now, I tried to take the first element of `route.params.who`, and it is the letter `m` (the first letter of `michael`, or `a[0]` if `a` = `michael`).

So I have

- an unexpected type `string[]` when I would expect `string`
- and that first element of this `string[]` is actually the first letter of the expected string

---

Note: the framework is [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/), but I do not think it is relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that creating type descriptions for route params is hard.

Route dynamic `params` can be defined using custom regex which allows matching single as well as [repeatable params](https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#repeatable-params). Typing this dynamically (to your specific route definition) is not possible. That's why route `params` type is declared as `Record<string, string | string[]>`

To solve your problem, just use [type casting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions):

```js
user.value = route.params.who as string
```